# How do I put a breakpoint in libc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have the following problem: my application exits with code 1. I'd like to set a breakpoint on libc's exit to know what causes this, however I have no idea how to do it. I am using MSVC 2012. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the last curly brace of main().  And single-step when it hits.  You'll step into the CRT source code, note the "mainret" variable.  Verify it is still 0, set a data breakpoint on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `atexit()` and a small utility function or the destructor of a global. The problem is though, when it exits, the stackframe of whatever caused it to exit is long gone. Also note that the program perhaps doesn't call `exit()` at all, but maybe `TerminateProcess()`. The fact that the text says "exited with" does not mean that the `exit()` function was called, returning from `main()` has the same effect.

My advise is to step through it in a debugger to find out which code causes the program to exit. That should allow you to quickly circe in on the problem. Also check the debug output for unusual things, like uncaught exceptions. Note that the "first chance exception" messages are misleading, as they are written even if the exception is caught. Still, if you suspect that, you can configure the IDE to stop at the place where an exception is thrown, which makes it easier to find that place in some cases.

Comment: Hi, doomster and thank you for your answer. I already tried stepping through the program. It goes thrugh the program absolutely fine up to the end. I get absolutely no exceptions or abnormal debugger messages.

Comment: I think I don't understand your problem then. If it goes fine up to the end, the next step is exiting. Just guessing, but do you `return true;` in `main()`, perhaps?

Comment: That's it. I just don't understand why exit code is not zero  but 1. I have return 0 at the end of my main and it ACTUALLY EXECUTES this line, but debugger says it ended with code 1.